# BeautifulSoup returns None even though there is a match?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
soap = BeautifulSoup('<a href="logout.asp"><script>i18n("Logout")</script></a>', 'html.parser')
match = soap.find('a', text='<script>i18n("Logout")</script>')
print(match)
```

Why the above code doesn't print the only  tag in my html?

I see None printed on the screen nothing more.

Comment: I suspect the embedded double quotes are the problem.  You may need to escape them.  But generally, I wouldn't search for things this way.  You're mixing tags with text in your search; generally, I would think you want to search for tags *or* text, or qualify your tag search with the text, etc.  Read the documentation on [find](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find).

Comment: There is no text to return just a script. Try doing `soap.find('a', href=True).text` and you will see `''` is returned.

Comment: @It_is_Chris I want all a tags which have this value between <a> and </a>

Answer (score 0):

Since you want all a tags which have `<script>i18n("Logout")</script>` between  and , try this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soap = BeautifulSoup('<a href="logout.asp"><script>i18n("Logout")</script></a>', 'html.parser')
match = soap.find('a').find('script', text='i18n("Logout")')
print(match)
```